# C# get SSL Certificate into X509Certificate with "Forbidden" error

Tags: c#, ssl, x509certificate

I have an issue when trying to get some SSL Certificate information.

Generally, the code works fine, but in some cases, I am getting a 403 Forbidden error. I want to get the certificate information even if this happens. There are also a couple of cases where I'm getting invalid logon credentials as well.

I want to get the `X509Certificate` object regardless of either of these issues.

If I use IE to browse them, it gives me the certificate information, regardless of the message.

So for the sample code, both `request` and `response` are defined as object variables, and `request` is set up properly before calling `getRequest()`.

This code works fine if there are no web errors, but if there is an error, the variable `response` is `null`.

Is there another way to get the `X509Certificate` into an object variable called `cert`, even seeing these errors?

I honestly don't care if I get the response working, I only care about the `X509Certificate`.

```
// callback used to validate the certificate in an SSL conversation
private static bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(
    object sender,
    X509Certificate certificate,
    X509Chain chain,
    SslPolicyErrors policyErrors
) {
    // allow any old dodgy certificate...
    log.write(0, "entering ValidateRemoeCertificate ");
    return true;
}

// getRequest 
private int getRequest()
{
    try {
        log.write(1, "Validating " + webHostName);
        // request.Method = method;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateRemoteCertificate);
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        response.Close();
    } catch (Exception w) {
        if (w.Message.Contains("401"))
        {
            log.write(4, "Web Site Authentication Required for " + host + ":" + port);
            return 401;
        }
        else if (w.Message.Contains("403"))
        {
            log.write(4, "Forbidden Access for " + host + ":" + port);
            return 403;
        }
        else
        {
            log.write(4, "Error Reading Web Site " + host + " Port " + port + " " + w.Message);
            return 400;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [SslStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) class instead. Use a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145056.aspx) that takes a [RemoteCertificateValidationCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback.aspx) delegate, which is called during [AuthenticateAsClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145060.aspx) to examine the server's certificate.

Comment: thank you very much akton... it worked and is now exactly what I need.  Much appreciated!